# Filter array with object that contains array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object

How can I make this

```
var foo = [{
  "number":[1, 2, 3],
  "id": [81, 82, 83]
}];
```

Into this

```
var foo = [{
  "number": 1,
  "id": 81
},{
  "number": 2,
  "id": 82
},{
  "number": 3,
  "id": 83
}]
```

I tried `.map()` and `.filter()` but they don't turn out the way I need it. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: post your code at least

Comment: Where are you getting the data that populates `foo` and why is it wrapped in an outer array? This looks like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and there is probably a solution to your real problem that does not involve doing strange object manipulation like this.

Comment: why is `foo` an array?

Comment: *"Any suggestions?"* ... yes, show us what you tried. The objective of Stackoverflow is to help you fix **your code** not to be a free code writing or tutorial service

Comment: Grab the first item, then the first key. Map those array values into objects by iterating over the keys.

Comment: Is your input always an array? Does it always contain one element? Is the element always an object? Does the object always have array values? Be as specific as possible and show your code

Comment: Does the *i* th element in foo[0].number always map to the corresponding element in foo[0].id?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Thank you!

Comment: @James Yes it does, I think I might have figured it out with Mr. Polywhirls answer but I'm having to do nested map() functions

Answer (score 1):

You could create a function for that:

```
function transform(values) {
  const result = [];
  values.forEach(value => {
    value.id.forEach((id, i) => {
      result.push({id, number: value.number[i]});
    });
  });
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While I find this to be an odd question, and I'm still hoping for a response regarding my suspicion this is [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), here is a possible approach you can use for whatever you're trying to do.

Let's assume that `foo` is a single object which only contains enumerable properties that are all arrays of equal length:

```js
var foo = {
  "number": [1, 2, 3],
  "id": [81, 82, 83]
}

function spread(obj) {
  // get the enumerable keys of your object
  var keys = Object.keys(obj)
  // initialize an empty array
  var array = []

  // for each key...
  keys.forEach(function (key) {
    // for each element in the array of the property...
    obj[key].forEach(function (value, index) {
      // if the array element does not contain an object
      // initialize an empty object in index
      var base = index < array.length ? array[index] : (array[index] = {})

      // assign the value to the key in the element
      base[key] = value
    })
  })

  // return the generated array
  return array
}

console.log(spread(foo))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map the array's object, and thee number array of each object into a new array, then concat the results to flatten the sub arrays into one array.

```js
var foo = [{
  "number":[1, 2, 3],
  "id": [81, 82, 83]
}];

var result = [].concat.apply([], foo.map(function(obj) { // map the array into sub arrays and flatten the results with concat
  return obj.number.map(function(n, i) { // map the number array
    return {
      number: n,
      id: obj.id[i] // get the id value by using the index
    };
  })
}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a list of objects based on the number of values within a given key.

So, you need to loop over the main list of objects. Inside that loop, you need to loop over the values for a key (i.e. pick the first). You will not need to use these values directly, they are just to determine how many records will be created in the final array. Lastly, you just iterate over the keys again and map the key-values pairs based on the current index.

The `Array.prototype.concat.apply([], ...arrays)` that happens at the end will combine all the arrays.

The function supports a single object or a list of objects.

```js
var foo = [{
  "number" : [ 1,  2,  3],
  "id"     : [81, 82, 83]
}, {
  "number" : [ 4,  5,  6],
  "id"     : [84, 85, 86]
}];

console.log(JSON.stringify(mapValues(foo), null, 4));

function mapValues(arr) {
  arr = !Array.isArray(arr) ? [arr] : arr;
  return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], arr.map(item => {
    return item[Object.keys(item)[0]].map((val, index) => {
      return Object.keys(item).reduce((obj, key) => {
        obj[key] = item[key][index];
        return obj;
      }, {});
    });
  }));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Here is another version that does not introduce much complexity.

```js
var foo = [{
  "number" : [1, 2, 3],
  "id"     : [81, 82, 83]
}, {
  "number" : [4, 5, 6],
  "id"     : [84, 85, 86]
}];

console.log(JSON.stringify(mapValues(foo), null, 4));

function mapValues(arr) {
  arr = !Array.isArray(arr) ? [arr] : arr;
  let records = [], fields;
  arr.forEach(item => {
    fields = fields || Object.keys(item);
    item[fields[0]].forEach((val, index) => {
      records.push(fields.reduce((obj, key) => {
        obj[key] = item[key][index];
        return obj;
      }, {}));
    });
  });
  return records;
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  top: 0;
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

#### Result

```
[{
    "number": 1,
    "id": 81
}, {
    "number": 2,
    "id": 82
}, {
    "number": 3,
    "id": 83
}, {
    "number": 4,
    "id": 84
}, {
    "number": 5,
    "id": 85
}, {
    "number": 6,
    "id": 86
}]
```